# NetLogo, accessing color of a patch

Tags: patch, netlogo

I am trying to apply the following condition:

```
if ( the color of patch -2 -1 is red )
[
   some commands
]
```

Could someone please tell me how to write this in NetLogo?

Comment: if you find this answer useful, you should accept it

Answer (score 4):

```
if ([pcolor] of patch -2 -1 = red) 
[

]
```

Pretty much how you put it but in code, read the tutorials and what not and this should be simple.  Note that you use pcolor for patches and color for turtles.