# How to write a basic NetLogo `if` statement for patch colors

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to apply the following condition:

```
if ( the color of patch -2 -1 is red ) [ some commands ]
```

Could someone please tell me how to write this in NetLogo?

Comment: possible duplicate of [NetLogo, accessing color of a patch](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3584034/netlogo-accessing-color-of-a-patch)

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the patch at coordinates (-2 1) then its:

```
ask (patch -2 1) with [pcolor = red] [commands]
```

or

```
ask (patch -2 1) [ if (pcolor = red) [commands]]
```

Comment: The second of these is right, but the first doesn't work. `with` requires an agentset.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a with to get the agentset like Jose M Vidal has suggested.

1) Using AgentSet

```
ask patches with [pcolor = black]  [ commands here ]
```

2) If you want to use an if condition specifically, write it as such:

```
ask patches [ if [pcolor] of self = black  [ commands here ] ]
```